# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the series $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$ I'm trying to prove its divergent but with no luck. It doesn't tend to $\infty$ as $n$ grows large and ratio test is inconclusive.
I have been trying to do a comparison test but all series less than $S$ that I was able to come up with were convergent. So I'm starting to suspect that the series might actually be convergent, any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try Stirling's formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}=\frac{C_{2n}^n}{4^n}=\frac{\sum (C_n^i)^2}{4^n}\geq\frac{\frac{(\sum C_n^i)^2}{n+1}}{4^n}=\frac{1}{n+1}$$ by vandermonde identity and QM-AM inequality.
and harmonic series is divergent so the series in question is also divergent.

Comment: Can you expand a little on how we got the last three inequalities/equalities?

Comment: Sorry I don't know vandermonde identity and QM-AM, I'm reading about them right now. But any more details would be helpful too!

Comment: Makes sense thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since in a comment you said you're not familiar with QM-AM and Vandermonde's identity, you may find the following useful.

**Hint:** Note that$$s_n=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}=\frac1{4^n}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)}{n!}$$so one has $$s_{n+1}=s_n\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{4(n+1)^2}=\frac{s_n}{2}\frac{2n+1}{n+1}.$$Use this to prove $s_n\ge\frac1{n+1}$ by induction.

Comment: $\frac{s_n}{2}\frac{2n+1}{n+1} \geq \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} < \frac{1}{n+1}$ so $s_{n+1} \geq \frac{1}{n+1}$ is not true.

Comment: @Shadowfirex: Yeah, but you want $s_{n+1}\ge\frac1{n+2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Raabe's Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html) with
$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=1-\dfrac{A}{n}+\dfrac{A_n}{n}=1-\dfrac{\frac12}{n}+\dfrac{A_n}{n}$$
where $A_n=\dfrac{1}{2(n+1)}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, then $A=\dfrac12<1$ shows the series diverges!

Answer (score 0):

Whatare you allowed to use? With Stirling's approximation 
$$
\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{ \pi n}}
$$
so the summand is $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ and

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}}
$$
and this diverges by comparing it to the Harmonic series.

Once again, this works if you are allowed to use the divergence of Harmonic series and Stirling's approximation.